# Does C# compiler convert and store static variables?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

My program uses the code:

```
Convert.ToDouble(Int32.MaxValue)
```

Fairly regularly. I was just curious about how this is handled by the compiler. Is it stored as a static double or is it executed in run time?

Comment: Why not `(double)Int32.MaxValue`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constant `Int32.MaxValue` is stored at compile time, and in fact your code would be converted to `Convert.ToDouble(0x7FFFFFFF)` at compile time. The equivalent IL is:

```
ldc.i4      FF FF FF 7F 
call        System.Convert.ToDouble
```

This value is also saved so it can be retrieved at run-time through reflection.

However, `Convert.ToDouble` is a function that is only evaluated at run-time.

As *minitech* suggests, `(double)Int32.MaxValue` is evaluated at compile-time. The equivalent IL is:

```
ldc.r8      00 00 C0 FF FF FF DF 41
```

Comment: Any resources you would recommend to learn about IL? I currently know nothing about it

Comment: @ThomasFarley Probably no better way to learn than to write some C#, download a free decompiler like ILSpy, and view the IL :)

Comment: @CuongLe This is exactly what I use most of the time, including in answer to this question.